# Sorting custom attribute not working in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, sorting

I need to sort the product collection by custom attribute called `popular` which having value `1` or `0`. Below is my code,

```
    $collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection1->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'status', 'eq' => 1)));
    $collection1->addAttributeToSelect(array(array('attribute'=> 'price')));
    $collection1->addAttributeToSelect(array(array('attribute'=> 'special_price')));
    $collection1->addAttributeToSort('popular', 'desc');
    foreach ($collection1 as $col) {
                        echo $col->getId();
                        echo '<br>';

    }
    exit;
```

Here I just printing the `product id` and every load it is showing different products. I re-indexed the products and I have set the product attribute options all to `yes` in **admin**. Like `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` to `yes`,  `Used in Product Listing` to `yes`, but still Im not getting unique product list. Is there something I missed here ..? And if we apply two sorting to the collections which sort will it take ?.  please help me.

**Note:** *I have tried with `price` attribute type for this attribute but still no luck (I thought if the attribute type is price then sorting will work correctly)*

**Update 1:** I already tried with `setorder`, but that is also not working.

Answer (score 3):

Please add attribute to select then apply sorting by using `order()`

```
    $collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection1->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection1->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => 'status', 'eq' => 1)));
    //$collection1->addAttributeToSort('popular', 'desc');
$collection1->getSelect()->order('popular DESC');
    foreach ($collection1 as $col) {
                        echo $col->getId();
                        echo '<br>';

    }
    exit;
```

Comment: Thanks Nalin, but still it is not working.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check

Comment: as per your new update, It will clear the old collection if it is already loaded, but unfortunately it is not working - tried, thanks.

Comment: please check now

Comment: Setorder thing I already tried, sorry for not updating in my question, and I tried again it is not working, Thanks for your continues help @nalin

Answer (score 0):

indeed to need to specify attributes to select by

`$collection->addAttributeToSelect(*);`

or

`$collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes());`

And to sort you have to use this:

`$collection->addAttributeToSort('you_custom_attribute_code');`

Hope it will help you.